# Does throwing an exception affect errno or set last error code

Tags: c++, gcc, throw, errno, getlasterror

Supposing the `Foo` constructor does not call any function that affect `errno` or similar status codes like `GetLastError()` on Windows, is it guaranteed that

```
throw Foo
```

does not affect any of these values. That said, can I post-pone the read of error code until the constructor of Foo? If not specified by the standard, I am most interested in the behaviour of GCC, GNU/Linux and MinGW-SJLJ variants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [`GetLastError()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is Windows specific and non standard.  Exceptions don't affect the value returned:  only calls to OS function update it (unless you call  `SetLastError()`).

Nevertheless, throwing an exception has potential impacts on automatic objects that were in scope:

> **15.2/1** As control passes from the point where an exception is thrown to a handler, destructors are invoked for all automatic objects
>   constructed since the try block was entered. The automatic objects are
>   destroyed in the reverse order of the completion of their
>   construction.

If the destructor of any such objects contains call to the OS, this might have an impact on `GetLastError()`.

***To summarize:*** First the `Foo` constructor is called, then the destructors of already completely constructed local objects is called, and finally the throw "transfers controls" to the nearest exception handler. So no library function is expected to be called. The standard uses the same wording ("transfer control" or "pass control") for any elementary flow control statements, such as break, continue, and goto.

Comment: Indeed, but is it guaranteed, then, that the exception handling code does not use any such syscalls?

Comment: But there is some black magic inside the throw statement I do not have complete knowledge of...

Comment: @Dolda2000 well, indeed, the local objects being destructed, their destructor might call OS functions (for example if an fstream was open)

Comment: @Christophe That only applies if these destructors are called before the construction of Foo.

Comment: @user877329 Not necessarily: the Foo constructor is called, then the destructors of (already completely constructed) local objects is called, then control is passed to the excpetion catcher.  [Demo](http://ideone.com/FsSVDh)

Comment: If Foo constructor is called first, then it is only a matter of what throw does before calling the ctor.

Comment: Nothing happens before.  The standard says that after, it "transfers controls" to the nearest exception handler (after the Foo construction). So no library function is expected to be called.  The standard uses the same wording ("transfer control" or "pass control") for any elementary flow control statements, such as break, continue, and goto.

Comment: @Christope Add the last comment to your answer and it is done.